# Initialize multiple C++-Arrays with common data

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization

I have a couple of const C++-Arrays which I'd like to initialize with different data, but the prefix will always be the same. This example compiles:

```
const int array_1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 5 };
const int array_2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 6 };
// ...
```

Is it possible to not specify the prefix (`1, 2, 3`) everytime? This compiles and illustrates it, with the drawback of using a macro:

```
#define prefix 1, 2, 3
const int array_1[] = { prefix, 5, 5 };
const int array_2[] = { prefix, 8, 7, 6 };
```

Requirements:

- No macros.
- You can use C++11, or if needed, C++14. Please specify what version is necessary.
- `std::array` instead of C-style arrays is allowed.

Comment: Do they have to be raw (C-style) arrays? Or are `std::array`s also possible?

Comment: @DyP std::array will be fine. If you use it, please just give requirements for which C++ version is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template<int... Is> struct seq {};
template<int N, int... Is> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};

template<class T, int N, class... Rs, int... Is>
constexpr auto append(seq<Is...>, T (&lhs)[N], Rs&&... rhs)
-> std::array<T, N+sizeof...(Rs)>
{
    return {{lhs[Is]..., std::forward<Rs>(rhs)...}};
}

template<class T, int N, class... Rs>
constexpr auto append(T (&lhs)[N], Rs&&... rhs)
-> decltype( append(gen_seq<N>{}, lhs, std::forward<Rs>(rhs)...) )
{
    return append(gen_seq<N>{}, lhs, std::forward<Rs>(rhs)...);
}

constexpr int prefix[] = {1,2,3};
constexpr auto array_1 = append(prefix, 5, 5);
constexpr auto array_2 = append(prefix, 8, 7, 6);

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "array_1: ";
    for(auto const& e : array_1) std::cout << e << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "array_2: ";
    for(auto const& e : array_2) std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I wish there was something already in the std libraries to do this. I'll accept in the next days if there will come no solution with less code. ;)

Comment: @Johannes In C++1y, we'll get the `seq` and sequence generation (`index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence`) as well as return type deduction (for ordinary functions). This reduces the code from 11 to 6 lines.

Answer (score 0):

As for me I have no other idea except to use a macro. For example

```
    #define COMMON_PART 1, 2, 3
    const int array_1[] = { COMMON_PART, 5, 5 };
    const int array_2[] = { COMMON_PART, 8, 7, 6 };
```

Comment: Fails the **No Macros** requirement of the OP

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this was mentioned in the original post ;)

Comment: Maybe. it means that I was not attentive.